# What auto layout constraints lets a subview to compress to 0 size when the parent's size decreases?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Trying to figure out what constraints do I need to add to a view-subview layout hierarchy that would allow the subview to auto resize when the parent view's size changes. Not using interface builder intentionally, `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `NO` for all participating views.

Below is a code snippet that tries to describe the situation:

```
UIView *canvas = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[canvas addSubview:container];

NSNumber *height = @(50);
NSNumber *margin = @(10);
NSDictionary *metrics = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(height, margin);

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(container);

NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(margin)-[container(height)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[canvas addConstraints:constraints];
NSLayoutConstraint *containerHeightConstraint = [constraints objectAtIndex:1]; // Know this is unsafe and shouldn't use the visual format in this case, but visual format serves SO purposes better

constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-(margin)-[container]-(margin)-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];
[canvas addConstraints:constraints];

UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[container addSubview:subView];

margin = @(5);
metrics = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(margin);
views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subView);
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(margin)-[subView]-(margin)-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[container addConstraints:constraints];
constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-(margin)-[subView]-(margin)-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views];
[container addConstraints:constraints];

[container layoutIfNeeded]; // Layout before animation

containerHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
    [container layoutIfNeeded]; // Animate container to 0 height
} completion:nil];
```

The question is what constraints do I need to add that would mimic the autoresize mask constraints that Interface Builder creates and would allow `subView` in the above example to shrink to 0 height as `container` shrinks.

If you could also explain the mechanics of such constraints that would help me understand Auto Layout better.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to set the height and width constant constrain to your subview when the container resizes.